# Ho can I store big quantity of data?

Tags: sql, node.js, database

I have to store packages of data retrieved from n machines every 10 seconds. These informations have to been saved into a db and stay here forever. Furthermore, data package has to be flexible (if tomorrow I want to add a new data I have to can do it).
First idea i have thougth is to save each machine package of data in a log file into a sql table but in short time I'd have enormous files hard to be read or written by a nodejs aplication. Also I'd need more space into db.
Is there a way to store big quantity of data and mantain high performance? I know nothing about big data storage but can it be the solution?

Comment: Define "big". Define "enormous".

Comment: Just do some back of the envelope math. How much data do you retrieve per cycle? How many cycles per day? What's your retention period? Once you know that, **test using different databases** and see how they perform. Simulate a year of writes, or more, if necessary.

Comment: I have to store a json of 50 elements every 10 seconds. So in a day, from only one machine I'd have 8500 rows of 50 data

Comment: Elements don't matter. Bytes do. What size are you talking about? Could you compress? How is this data used? is it queried often? Does it need to be indexed?

Comment: I'd test this against a Postgres 13 database with a `JSONB` column and see how much data you can cram in on the hardware you're intending to use and find out where it falls over. My guess is you'll fill up the disk space first.

Comment: You think I can use Postgres and create a table for each machine with its log data inside? Or your advice is also use blob inside a table and save logs here?

Comment: No, no, not table per machine. One table with a machine identifier column. If you have problems with scaling look at using table partitioning at that point, or horizontal sharding. I'm not saying "blob", I'm saying *specifically*, `JSONB`. It's a compact form for JSON data.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new with this type of data. You suggest to use this json field but I have to insert all json in a single partitioned table?

Comment: You don't "have" to, but I'm suggesting that's a good place to start. If you need to query or report on this data it may be worth breaking out parts of that data into proper columns so you can index them or select them easily. For other data that's more extraneous, stuffing it in a JSONB column for posterity is fairly efficient. This is for a situation where you have a lot of write activity and very little reading.

Comment: You can do a lot with a simple schema, some server tuning, and use of partitioning if you're having problems, but this is all highly situational. My advice: Try the simplest design that can possibly work, and stress it as hard as you can with testing to see if you can get it to break so you know what the limits of it are.

Comment: I omitted to say that data have to been retrieved in a front-end application which show a dashboard with machine information along the time. Is this a problem in your opinion?

Comment: If you're looking to absorb a lot of *immutable* data investigate both Postgres and Cassandra.

Comment: Thank you so mutch for your help!!! I'm gonna follow your advices